# Django pipeline: 500 response error

Tags: django, django-pipeline

I'm trying to use django-pipeline, but I get a 500 error response for the generated static files, this is my configuration:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
        'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
        'pipeline.finders.CachedFileFinder',
    )
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
    PIPELINE_ENABLED = True
    PIPELINE_DISABLE_WRAPPER = True
    PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
    PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yuglify.YuglifyCompressor'
    PIPELINE_YUGLIFY_BINARY = '/opt/local/bin/uglifyjs'
```

I don't understand why other static files under `/static` are reachable while pipeline ones are not, for example: `/static/js/file1.js` and `/static/js/file2.js` are properly served, but `/static/js/scripts.js` (which are the combination of the previuos files) no (the file are physically located with the others).

(I'm running Django 1.5.2 with the development server)

**EDIT:
After upgrading to pipeline 1.3.15 (I was using 1.3.14) it's now working!**

Comment: Can you include the 500 response?

Comment: it seems a simple upgrade solved all my problems! :P